# Удалить повторяющиеся строки в файле

Tags: php, скиллометрия

Скорее просто разминочный вопрос, хочу узнать кто сможет победить мой вариант:

```
file_put_contents('2',array_unique(file('1')));
```

Соответственно читаем из 1 пишем в 2
Кто победит по количеству кода ?

Answer (score 5):

Не знаю как по количеству кода, но по скорости, пожалуй, такой вариант быстрее:

```
file_put_contents('2',array_flip(array_flip(file('1'))));
```

Comment: Забавно и даже работает ;) не знал такого хитрого приема

Comment: С хитрыми приемами надо быть осторожнее. Но в данном случае - прокатит.

Comment: Плюс за хитрозадость).

Comment: О! Я получил + за хотрозадость от самого линга. Фигасе... Все, теперь неделю этот пост мыть не буду.

Answer (score 2):

```
exec('sort 1 | uniq > 2');
```

Comment: отлично, жалко не указал платформу ;) хорошо

Comment: Ну, по КОЛИЧЕСТВУ кода - это победитель... :) Другое дело, это не совсем уже PHP. Да и не везде позволят exec юзать.

Comment: Зато по количеству используемой памяти максимально эффективное :)

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, сравнение памяти в данном случае бессмысленно, имхо)

Comment: От чего же бессмысленно? Проверил все варианты на sql дампе в 110мб, ~600 000 строк.

    $ time php -r 'file_put_contents("1",array_unique(file("dump.sql"))); var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage());'
    int(356405592)

    real 0m2.857s
    user 0m1.935s
    sys 0m0.910s

    $ time php -r 'file_put_contents("2",array_flip(array_flip(file("dump.sql")))); var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage());'
    int(456105688)

    real 0m2.144s
    user 0m1.105s
    sys 0m1.036s

    $ time ./sort
    
В моем варианте расход памяти 205360 kB (через PHP проблематично померить) и real 0m0.762s

Comment: Какой смысл сравнивать `$a = array(1,2,3);` и `int c[] = {1,2,3};`?.
В данном случае сравнение памяти - ничего не говорит о том, сколько необходимо!!! памяти каждому из алгоритмов.

Comment: Т.е. готовые результаты теста, приведенные выше, вам ничего не говорят? :)

Comment: Они говорят только то, что и так известно: php медленнее чем компилируемые языки)

Comment: У unix утилиты sort есть ключик -u. Тогда самая короткая (и думаю самая эффективная) запись 

exec ('sort -u 1 > 2');

Это если я правильно насчет вызова внешних команд из ПХП понял.